# jQuery If Statements Only Working For Smooth Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

In my code, I have a jQuery function that is called when a user clicks a link with a certain class name (there are two of these links on any given page). One is to smooth-scroll to the footer of the website. The other is to smooth-scroll back to the top. They're in the same function, but only the link to scroll to the footer is working.

```
function smoothScrolling() {
  $(".smoothScroll a").click(function(e) {
    var $scrolltype = $(this).attr("data-scrolltype");
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("Scrolling to " + $scrolltype + "...");

    if($scrolltype === 'footer') {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".app__footer").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    } if($scrolltype === 'header') {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#primaryMenu").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    }

    return false;
  });
}
smoothScrolling();
```

The `preventDefault();` and `return false` are used to prevent ajax page loading.

The smooth scroll to the footer works perfectly. Despite being the exact same code used for both buttons, the link to scroll to the header does not work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't see the html it's hard to tell what's wrong but your code is fine. Here what you can check :

1 - Make sure the menu as the id `primaryMenu`.

2 - Make sure the link in the footer as `data-scrolltype="header"`

3 - Make sure the footer link as a parent with `smoothScroll` class

Good luck.

Comment: I checked all of these things before posting, and double checked just now. Everything in the HTML / JS is accurate, which is just adding to the confusion about why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or your html so we can make it work. If your code get in the === 'header' section. What's the value of $("#primaryMenu").offset().top ?

Comment: You could simply make this $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 2000);
Since the menu is always at top.

Comment: I believe it's an issue with the way Angular.js is creating these elements. For some reason it's duplicating the link to bring a user to the top of the page, but not including the data-scrolltype attribute on the duplicated link (though it is on the first instance of the link).

Thanks for your help anyway.